# error (13) no permission to execute /etc/init during NFS rootfs mount

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a problem to execute the init during kernel bootup. Currently I'm porting android to a customized target board. The kernel is a customized kernel, and NFS rootfs is aosp root fs, basically it's system folder in output folder built from aosp. I could mount sucessfully but kernel cannot execute /etc/init and error return is 13(no permision).

I already chmod 777 on all of files in the file system and just don't understand how come kernel does not have the permission to execute it. Below is the boot up log

[image]

Comment: *"I could mount sucessfully"* -- I don't agree, since it's mounted readonly.

Comment: The problem has been solved, I did not start the right init process. In android, the init is /init, not /etc/init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I did not start the right `init` process. In `Android`, the `init` is `/init`, not `/etc/init`.

Comment: this is the answer